# How to check if leap year date is valid

Tags: python, validation, leap-year

I am trying to check if the date is valid, but I am stuck on trying to find out if a leap year date is valid. I keep on getting this message that says:

LAST RUN on 02/11/2018, 12:49:03
Your function said that 29/2/1754 is valid, but it's invalid.

I know that this is not a leap year. I am trying to return a value of False every time a year is not a leap year, in the validDate Function.

Any info you can give me, would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

```
def isLeapYear(y):
    assert y > 1753, False
    return y % 4 == 0 and (y % 100 != 0 or y % 400 == 0)


def daysIn(y, m):
    assert 1 <= m <= 12, False
    if m == 9 or m == 4 or m == 6 or m == 11:
        return 30
    elif m == 1 or m == 'March' or m == 'May' or m == 'July':
        return 31
    elif m == 8 or m == 10 or m == 12 or m == 3 or m == 5 or m == 7:
        return 31
    elif m == 2 and isLeapYear(y) is True:
        return 29
    elif m == 2 and isLeapYear(y) is False:
        return 28
    else:
        return False


def validDate(y, m, d):

    try:
        if daysIn(y, m) and isLeapYear(y):
            return True
    except AssertionError:
        return False

    if y > 1753 and 1 <= m <= 12 and 1 <= d <= 31:
        return True
    elif y == isLeapYear(y) and m == 2 and d == 29:
        return False
    else:
        return False


if __name__ == "__main__":
    isLeapYear(2012)
    daysIn(2012, 10)
    validDate(1752, 10, 10)
```

Comment: `daysIn` returns a number, but you're just using it in a condition as if it is a boolean. You're not checking if your `d` is within the length specified by `daysIn`.

Comment: don't use `assert` to check user input. Raise an exception explicitly, `ValueError` would be a good choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the standard library datetime module.

```
from datetime import date

def validDate(y, m, d):
    try:
        date(y, m, d)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

Comment: Ok but how did I check if a leap year is valid or not ?

Comment: @KhatraAhmed: Your check if a year is a leap year is correct, but the rest of your code is not.

Comment: @KhatraAhmed: If the date is invalid, the function returns `False`. The `datetime` module takes leapyears into account.

Comment: @HåkenLid: I understand but, I want it to be within a specifc range and not all the years and I want my other asserts from the other functions to be used as well.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the `validDate` function, where you don't check the day but only if the month has days (which is True for every month).

```
def validDate(y, m, d):
    assert 1 <= d <= daysIn(y, m)
```

or if `validDate` should return a boolean, try:

```
def validDate(y, m, d):
    if y <= 1754:
        return False
    if not (1 <= m <= 12):
        return False
    if m in (1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12):
        days = 31
    elif m == 2:
        leap = y % 4 == 0 and (y % 100 != 0 or y % 400 == 0)
        days = 29 if leap else 28
    else:
        days = 30
    return 1 <= d <= days
```